# Javascript code for loop don't show my desired ouput

Tags: javascript

My code below don't show my desired output.

```
for (var row=1;row<=8;row++) {
    for (var i=1;i<=4-(4-row);i++) {
        document.write("#");
    }

    document.write("</br>");
}
```

I want the output like this

[image]

Comment: What is the actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var x = 8;
var y = parseInt(x / 2);

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < y - Math.abs(i - y); j++)
    document.write('#');
  document.write('<br/>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should add Math.abs method

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (var row=1;row<=8;row++) {
    for (var i=1;i<=4-(row<=4?4-row:row-4);i++) {
        document.write("#");
    }

    document.write("</br>");
}
```